# How to read properties from DLL before Assembly.LoadFile()

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

My program have a pluginManager module, it can load a DLL file and run DLL's methods, but I need read the DLL properties before `Assembly.LoadFile()`. What should I do?

I readed about Assembly documents, they read properties after `Assembly.LoadFile()`, you know Assembly no UnLoad() Method, so I must read properties before LoadFile()
[image]

```
    private void ImprotZip(string path)
    {
        /*
        1、create tempDir, uppackage to tempDir
        2、Load Plugin DLL, Load plugin dependent lib DLL
        */
        string tempDirectory = CreateRuntimeDirectory(path);
        string[] dllFiles = Directory.GetFiles(tempDirectory);
        ///Load DlL
        foreach(string dll in dllFiles)
        {
            ImprotDll(dll, false);
        }
        string libPath = string.Format("{0}\\lib\\", tempDirectory);
        if (!Directory.Exists(libPath))
            return;
        string[] dlls = Directory.GetFiles(libPath);
        ///Load plugin dependent lib DLL
        foreach(string dll in dlls)
        {
            try
            {
                //filtering same DLL 
                //if(Dll.properties.AssemblyProduct != "something")
                //continue;
                Assembly.LoadFile(dll);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.Log();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to enforce queryable metadata to be placed in a separate file alongside the target dll?

Comment: you mean's i can creat an xml document for the plugin dll file ?

Comment: You should post some more code,  might be a better overall way to do what you want, this sounds like something might benefit from some design tweaks.  Or post on StackExchange -CodeReview.

Comment: I wanna filterable same DLL, if I load same DLL the program will be crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo.aspx) is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can load assemblies into a reflection-only context using [`Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0et80c7k(v=vs.110).aspx).

I would still create an app domain for the reflection only context so you can unload the domain when you are done. You can create app domains by using the [`AppDomain.CreateDomain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.createdomain(v=vs.110).aspx) method. You should be doing this for plugins anyway so you can unload them when you are done.

Comment: if I load same DLL I'm afraid the program will be crash

Answer (score 0):

### try wid this code

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, bargs) =>
                {

```
                String dllName = new AssemblyName(bargs.Name).Name + ".dll";
                var assem = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                String resourceName = assem.GetManifestResourceNames().FirstOrDefault(rn => rn.EndsWith(dllName));
                if (resourceName == null) return null; // For null assembly
                using (var stream = assem.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
                {
                    Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
                    stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                    return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
                }
            };
```